# how to convert baseclass to subclass(subclass s = basceclass as subclass, but i dont' know this subclass type)

Tags: c#

For example:

```
   class a { }
   class b : a { }
   class c : a { }
   ....

   List<a> a = new List<a>();
   a.Add(new b());
   c.Add(new c());
   ....
```

There are lots of subclass inherit a, but i don't know which one. how to convert one of the elements into subclasses, such as ( a[i] as subclass ) the subclass which I don't know but it inherits a ? 
   I search in Google, many answers tell me to use reflection and Assembly.GetIntance, but  I think it create a new object, all the data owned by the subClass will be lost.
  Hope for help.

Comment: Smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... What is the greater goal you want to achieve? [Edit] the question and elaborate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Do you want to use `a.OfType<c>().ToList()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert to a type which you don't know (but it is not clear why you think you need to do that, hence @stickybit's comments about this being an XY problem). If you are trying to determine what type an object is so you can convert to it, then the [is operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) can be used to do that, or [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) can be used, although in many (most?) cases it is better from a design standpoint to add a [virtual method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) to the superclass and override it in each subclass to do something different, so that you can retrieve an element from your List as an instance of the superclass and call the virtual method on it without needing to know which specific subclass the object actually is.

Comment: I want to load the subclass into the PropertyGrid, but I don't want to build too many subclass objects, so I want to get the subclass through the parent class and then transform it, and then load the subclass into the PropertyGrid